# iAd question iPhone

Tags: iphone, iad

Have a quick question on iAd

I would like to create a free app and  make apple display iAds. I can get the test Ad displayed. From what I understand once I put my App in Apple store real Ads will show up after accepting the iAd contract.

So,  for example if Nissan Ad shows up in my app , then will I get paid by apple ...???
Is there a cost associated for iAd contract ...???

I don't want my App to show up on others app under ad banner, but I would like others app to show up as Ad in my App ad banner.

Thanks for clarifying the questions...!!!

Comment: There's a cost to be a developer and have your app in the app store :)

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay 99$ to get into the app store. But once you are there you will get money from iADs.
But if your app isn't awesome you won't get rich with that.

I have a kinda niche application (but awesome) in the store which gets downloaded around 100 times a day.

And my income from ads (I use adwhirl to get iad, admob and inmobi) is like $3 a month or so.

Last month I implemented In-App-Purchase and now I get more money every day through IAP than I got in a month with ads.

Nobody will see your ads if nobody will use your app. You should ask yourself if your app is good enough to be used.

And from what you wrote I think that you will waste $99.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in order to be accepted into the app store in the first place, your app has to be useful for more than just displaying iAds.

Comment: so what with farting, lighter or shotgun apps

Comment: Section 2.11 of the App Store Review Guidelines: `Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps.`

Comment: don't know when they started to use those examples. But as far as I remember the `don't duplicate apps` rule was in there since day 1. But even day 1 was only in september 2010 or so.